# Show all tables in sybase database with a specific column value int

Tags: sql, search, sybase

I want to write sybase query return all tables with column name is customer_id and customer_id is 123.
For column name, I can do something like this:

```
SELECT o.name, c.name
FROM sysobjects o, 
     syscolumns c
WHERE c.id = o.id
AND c.name LIKE 'customer_id'
```

How can I return all tables in sybase which contains customer_id = 123?

Comment: You have to write dynamic SQL.  This information is not in the metadata tables.

Comment: Thank you. I will try